# DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '0' error message:

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

> > DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '0' error message:
> > 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query:
> > org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> > Task 0 in stage 293.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
> > 0.3 in stage 293.0 (TID 1361) (10.139.64.7
>
> executor 0): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
> org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary
> at
> org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToInt(Dictionary.java:45)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToInt(ParquetDictionary.java:42)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector.getInt(OnHeapColumnVector.java:321)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.$anonfun$next$1(ArrowConverters.scala:226)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:238)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:202)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$3.(ArrowConverters.scala:340)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$.toHybridCloudResultIterator(ArrowConverters.scala:333)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.execution.arrowcollect.CloudStoreCollector$.$anonfun$hybridCollect$3(CloudStoreCollector.scala:180)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:903)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:903)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)     at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)    at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)    at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)   at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:826)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:829)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:684)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServerErrors$.runningQueryError(HiveThriftServerErrors.scala:47)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$thriftserver$SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$execute(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:435)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2$$anon$3.$anonfun$run$2(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:257)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ThriftLocalProperties.withLocalProperties(ThriftLocalProperties.scala:123)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ThriftLocalProperties.withLocalProperties$(ThriftLocalProperties.scala:48)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.withLocalProperties(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:52)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2$$anon$3.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:235)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2$$anon$3.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:220)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:269)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 293.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
> 0.3 in stage 293.0 (TID 1361) (10.139.64.7 executor 0): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
> org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary
> at
> org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToInt(Dictionary.java:45)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToInt(ParquetDictionary.java:42)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector.getInt(OnHeapColumnVector.java:321)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.$anonfun$next$1(ArrowConverters.scala:226)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:238)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:202)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$3.(ArrowConverters.scala:340)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$.toHybridCloudResultIterator(ArrowConverters.scala:333)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.execution.arrowcollect.CloudStoreCollector$.$anonfun$hybridCollect$3(CloudStoreCollector.scala:180)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:903)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:903)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)     at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)    at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)    at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)   at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:826)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:829)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:684)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3029)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2976)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2970)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2970)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1390)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1390)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1390)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3238)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3179)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3167)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
> at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2637)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.execution.arrowcollect.RDDBatchCollector.runSparkJobs(RDDBatchCollector.scala:79)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.execution.arrowcollect.RDDBatchCollector.collect(RDDBatchCollector.scala:122)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.execution.arrowcollect.CloudStoreCollector$.hybridCollect(CloudStoreCollector.scala:185)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.execution.arrowcollect.CloudStoreCollector$.hybridCollect(CloudStoreCollector.scala:230)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.CompressedHybridCloudStoreFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:166)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.CompressedHybridCloudStoreFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:161)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.collectResult$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:589)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.computeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:596)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$getOrComputeResultInternal$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:542)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResultInternal(ResultCacheManager.scala:541)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeHybridCloudStoreResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:506)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeHybridCloudStoreCollectResult(SparkPlan.scala:450)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectToHybridCloudStoreResults$1(Dataset.scala:3180)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3951)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:239)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:386)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:186)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:141)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:336)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3949)  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToHybridCloudStoreResults(Dataset.scala:3179)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HybridCloudStoreResultHandler.(HybridCloudStoreResultHandler.scala:58)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ResultHandlerFactory.createResultHandler(ResultHandlerFactory.scala:231)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$thriftserver$SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$execute(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:405)
> ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
> org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary
> at
> org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToInt(Dictionary.java:45)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToInt(ParquetDictionary.java:42)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector.getInt(OnHeapColumnVector.java:321)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.$anonfun$next$1(ArrowConverters.scala:226)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:238)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:202)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$3.(ArrowConverters.scala:340)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$.toHybridCloudResultIterator(ArrowConverters.scala:333)
> at
> com.databricks.sql.execution.arrowcollect.CloudStoreCollector$.$anonfun$hybridCollect$3(CloudStoreCollector.scala:180)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:903)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:903)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)     at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)    at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)    at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)   at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:826)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:829)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:684)
> ... 3 more '. Details:
> DataSourceKind=Databricks
> DataSourcePath={"host":"adb-762200519378203.3.azuredatabricks.net","httpPath":"sql/protocolv1/o/762200519378203/0414-052221-ztf6ehdy"}'''
> OdbcErrors=[Table]
>
> 1. The schema of newly created parquet file is same as the previous one. root  |-- Brand: integer (nullable = true)  |-- Market: integer
>    (nullable = true)  |-- year: string (nullable = true)  |-- imagery:
>    string (nullable = true)  |-- campaign: string (nullable = true)  |--
>    uplift: double (nullable = true)  |-- efficiency: double (nullable =
>    true)  |-- runid: string (nullable = true)  |-- run_Brand: string
>    (nullable = true)  |-- run_Market: string (nullable = true)  |--
>    runid_Year: string (nullable = true)  |-- runid_Quarter: string
>    (nullable = true)
>
>    root  |-- Brand: integer (nullable = true)  |-- Market: integer (nullable = true)  |-- year: string (nullable = true)  |-- imagery:
>    string (nullable = true)  |-- campaign: string (nullable = true)  |--
>    uplift: double (nullable = true)  |-- efficiency: double (nullable =
>    true)  |-- runid: string (nullable = true)  |-- run_Brand: string
>    (nullable = true)  |-- run_Market: string (nullable = true)  |--
>    runid_Year: string (nullable = true)  |-- runid_Quarter: string
>    (nullable = true)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), then update your question with specific details, simplified examples to support your explanation, and code/configuration/links you have tried so far.